# App Crashes while Loading Interstitial Ads

Tags: java, android, admob

I'm trying to load an ad. While trying, the app crashes and exits.

I'm using Firebase for database and more and it's working until it gets to load the ad. Here are my Dependencies:

```
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
```

Here's what the Log Cat Shows:

```
    05-25 02:41:06.158 1562-4610/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.example.johnn.myfirstapp/.FullDetails (has extras)} from uid 10074 on display 0
    05-25 02:41:06.164 3956-3984/com.example.johnn.myfirstapp V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 4475
    05-25 02:41:06.173 3956-3984/com.example.johnn.myfirstapp V/FA: Activity paused, time: 26769028
    05-25 02:41:06.176 3956-3956/com.example.johnn.myfirstapp V/FA: onActivityCreated
    05-25 02:41:06.187 3956-3984/com.example.johnn.myfirstapp D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=4475, _sc=DetailsActivity, _si=1459254922483070610}]
    05-25 02:41:06.213 3956-3956/com.example.johnn.myfirstapp D/DynamitePackage: Instantiated singleton DynamitePackage.
Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraMobileAdsSettingManagerCreatorImpl
    05-25 02:41:06.230 3956-3956/com.example.johnn.myfirstapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/webview/lib/x86
    05-25 02:41:06.230 3956-3956/com.example.johnn.myfirstapp D/ApplicationLoaders: ignored Vulkan layer search path /system/app/webview/lib/x86:/system/app/webview/webview.apk!/lib/x86:/system/lib:/vendor/lib for namespace 0xa7b80110
    05-25 02:41:06.231 3956-3956/com.example.johnn.myfirstapp I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.webview version 52.0.2743.100 (code 275610010)
    05-25 02:41:06.243 3956-3956/com.example.johnn.myfirstapp I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 1 ms (timestamps 9107-9108)
Expected native library version number "52.0.2743.100", actual native library version number "52.0.2743.100"
    05-25 02:41:06.246 3956-3956/com.example.johnn.myfirstapp V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider: Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {d77ee50}
    05-25 02:41:06.246 3956-3956/com.example.johnn.myfirstapp I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "52.0.2743.100", actual native library version number "52.0.2743.100"
    05-25 02:41:06.246 3956-3956/com.example.johnn.myfirstapp I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(143)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
    05-25 02:41:06.255 3956-3956/com.example.johnn.myfirstapp I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
    05-25 02:41:06.275 2550-3996/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=auto,name=_e,params=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=136]
    05-25 02:41:06.279 2550-3996/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Saving event, name, data size: _e, 70
Event recorded: Event{appId='com.example.johnn.myfirstapp', name='_e', params=Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=4475, _sc=DetailsActivity, _si=1459254922483070610}]}
    05-25 02:41:06.283 2550-3996/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 14881
    05-25 02:41:06.286 2550-3996/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 11
    05-25 02:41:06.359 3956-3956/com.example.johnn.myfirstapp I/cr_DRP: No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
    05-25 02:41:16.162 1562-1578/system_process W/ActivityManager: Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
    05-25 02:41:54.927 1562-1578/system_process W/BroadcastQueue: Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{f953a12 u0 android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED} - receiver=android.os.BinderProxy@62765e3, started 60001ms ago
    05-25 02:41:54.928 1562-1578/system_process W/BroadcastQueue: Receiver during timeout: ResolveInfo{63bbe0 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.icingsync.IcingCorporaChangedReceiver m=0x208000}
    05-25 02:41:54.932 1562-1578/system_process I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3682 SIG: 3
```

Is possible that it is crashing because of Google Play Services in The Emulator?

Comment: Can you provide the code where it crashes? Which activity is it crashing? As soon as it opens?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've made a slight edit to your post to fix some small typos etc, but as @sanjeev suggests, you're much more likely to get good answers if you include the code where the app is crashing. Even better if you can provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as described in the [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) section.

Comment: The app goes through 3 activities. The code that just loads the Ad is in the third one and the code that Shows the Ad is in a Method that it's called when the user taps the back button.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got on the 3rd Activity's **onCreate** Method:

```
    try{
        mInterstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        mInterstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() { }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) { }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {  }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() { }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                Intent adsIntent = new Intent(FullDetails.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                adsIntent.putExtra("ID", categoryId);
                startActivity( adsIntent);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        final String tag = "ErrCode:";
        Log.v(tag, ex.getMessage());
    }
```

That's where the App Crashes, Without it the App goes Smooth.

Comment: Hi thank you for the code.. But you haven't sent the logcat of error. The logcat which you provided doesn't have the error..

Comment: **Point to note:**  The ad unit id which you generated for your app should not be used while debugging. There is a separate id provided by google to be used while debugging.

Comment: The Log Cat above is what I get when the App Crashes.

Comment: Yes I did, weird is that in my actual hardware device the code is actually working.

Comment: Haha have you tried adding an emulator with diff config? probably has something to do with screen resolution/ version.